# C# Class Property That Can Hold an Integer or String

Tags: c#, json, class, properties

I am creating a class that I need convert to JSON but I need one property to be able to contain an integer or string (property value Below):

```
AISFormService obj = new AISFormService();

obj.formActions.Add(new FormAction { type = "New", controlID = 33, command = 
"Enter", value = "K2F" });

obj.formActions.Add(new FormAction { type = "New", controlID = 33, command = 
"Enter", value = 777 });


 public class FormAction
 {
     public string type { get; set; }
     public int controlID { get; set; }
     public string value { get; set; }
     public string command { get; set; }
 }

 public class AISFormService
 {
     public List<FormAction> formActions = new List<FormAction>();
     public string Role { get; set; }
     public string DeviceName { get; set; }
     public string Token { get; set; }
     public string MaxPageSize { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: you can use `Object` but you will lose type safety

Comment: First please describe *why* you need it to hold two datatypes. `int` can easily convert to and from a `string`, and it is easy to test if a `string` is an `int`. Wouldn't that be simpler?

Answer (score 3):

One way is that, you can make the `value` property instance of type `Object` for that, but you will lose type safety and when accessing value you would need to check it's type first like:

```
public Object value { get; set; }
```

now you can store any type of value in it:

```
obj.formActions.Add(new FormAction { type = "New", controlID = 33, 
                                     command ="Enter", value = "K2F" });

obj.formActions.Add(new FormAction { type = "New", controlID = 33, 
                                     command = "Enter", value = 777 });
```

in your case both `string` and `int` , but you will have to check before casting it to particular type to be on safe side:

```
if(value is int)
{
  var integerValue = Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
if(value is String)
{
  var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "public string value { get; set; }" Then it will work fine. Means when you will add new property to FormAction Model then you can simply convert the integer to string. See below

```
obj.formActions.Add(new FormAction { type = "New", controlID = 33, command = 
"Enter", value = "K2F" });

obj.formActions.Add(new FormAction { type = "New", controlID = 33, command = 
"Enter", value = "777" });
```

When you are fetching it you can use `Convert.ToInt32()` to convert that string type to integer type. I hope it will work for you. let me know if you have any other query.

Comment: I would modify to say, "When you are examining `FormAction.value`, you can use `int.TryParse(value, out intValue)` to determine whether or not `value` is an integer type, and to convert it to an integer if it is".

Comment: Yes @RufusL .We can use this. In this way we can handle errors also. Thanks for you update.